# GDB comparing an existent character with a non-existent character?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb

I am currently trying to hone my skills in reading assembly in GDB and I ran into some weirdness when trying to read a character in GDB, and I am not sure what is going on.

For some context, the file I am looking at is compiled, there is no .c function though the code was compiled in c. It is essentially a 'bomb' assignment file, where specific inputs are required to get to the next section of the code, and this code comes from testing one of the inputs against whatever the answer is supposed to be.

The code that contains the character I am trying to read is as follows:

```
cmp -0x1(%rbp),%al
je 0x400acf <nextpartofcode>
```

I am trying to read the -0x1(%rbp), so I inputted `print/c $rbp-1` to try to look at it and GDB printed: `175 '\257'`. Assuming that this output meant that the comparion would succeed if put in the ASCII character 175, however, when I inputted the character (it looks like >>) it was shown as `-62 '\302'`.

I also tried reading the value as an integer, octal value, decimal value, string, and hex value with the same amount of success, and I am at a lost at what else I can try. What exactly is happening here? Am I looking in the wrong place (ie is -0x1(%rbp) not $rbp-1)? Am I reading the value as something it isn't (I was told it should be a char, but is it something else)? Should I be looking somewhere else for the value? I'm stuck, and I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: `$rbp-1` is the address; you need to dereference it.  (Use GDB's `x` command to eXamine memory at an address, or use C syntax to dereference a pointer for `print`, like `p /c *(char*)($rbp-1)`.  You were printing the low byte of the address as a char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$rbp-1` is the address; you need to dereference it.  (Use GDB's `x` command to eXamine memory at an address, or use C syntax to dereference a pointer for `print`, like `p /c *(char*)($rbp-1)`.

You were printing the low byte of the address as a char.